# No valid crumb error while triggering jenkins job via python requests.POST()

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to trigger jenkins job via python requests.POST()

```
reply = requests.post(url,
                      data=data,
                      cookies=self.__cookies,
                      auth=(self.__user, self.__pass),
                      files=files,
                      )
```

Received error:
No valid crumb was included in request for //job/Deploy/job/JOBNAME/buildWithParameters by . Returning 403.

Then Tried to pass crumb in header using the following code:

```
session = requests.Session()
crum = session.get('https://xxxxxx.xxx.net:7xxx/crumbIssuer/api/json',
                    auth=(self.__user, self.__pass)).json() 
reply = requests.post(url,
                      data=data,
                      cookies=self.__cookies,
                      params={crum['crumbRequestField']: crum['crumb']},
                      auth=(self.__user, self.__pass),
                      headers={crum['crumbRequestField']: crum['crumb']},
                      files=files,
                      )
```

Received following error:

Found invalid crumb 09ee0x69284910425bd94378a1735b3471826e8d5ec077c526562. If you are calling this URL with a script, please use the API Token instead. More information: https://jenkins.io/redirect/crumb-cannot-be-used-for-script

we are looking for a solution with via requests.post()

Answer (score 2):

To get it to work you need a valid session, auth and crumb. We also use tokens, so I've added that as well

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = auth
    crumb = s.get(jenkins_url + "crumbIssuer/api/json").json()['crumb']
    s.headers.update({"token": token, "Jenkins-Crumb": crumb})
```

then we can

```
    s.post(url)
```

and we get back a 201 Created. It looks like you got everything except you're not doing it inside the session, but instead with a bare request. It's probably sufficient to just replace the `requests.post` with `session.post`